# Xml files in Android Studio - Remove spaces inside tags in layout files

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea

On Android Studio is there a way to remove unnecessary spaces between the attributes and 'end tags' (">" and "/>") when formating xml files?

I can't see this configuration "Code Style" options.

[image]

Based on the accept answer below I got a configuration that work for me:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Android Studio's **Preferences**, go to **Editor > Code Style > XML**.  Then select the Android tab on the far right.  There are options in this tab to customize the formatting of Android XML files (manifest, layouts, etc.).  Make sure **Use custom formatting settings for Android XML files** is checked.  Then you can just format that file like you do any other file **Code > Reformat Code**.

To get rid of the space before closing tags, go to the **Other** tab.  Under **Spaces** make sure **In empty tag** and **After tag name** are un-checked.

[image]

Comment: Yes, I had seen this tab, but there is not a option to remove spaces in tags like I want. At least I could not identify which one it is.

Comment: Added onto my answer.  I believe it is the "In empty tag" checkbox under the "Other" tab.

Comment: It works with a slightly different configuration. thank you.